# Is it possible to limit the number of cpus a user can use at the same time in SLURM?

Tags: unix, slurm

I found the MaxJobs option and combined with MaxCpus this sets an upper limit to the number of cpus someone can use but it also stimulates them to always max out the number of cpus you can use per job. Would it be possible to set a maximum number of cpus someone can use and then let them decide how many jobs they will use to utilize their available cpus?

So if I set MaxJobs to 5 and maxcpus to 10 one user can use 50 cpus at ones but only if they max out their cpus per job which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this is by setting the QOSMaxCpuPerUserLimit to 50 while setting the maxjobs limit to 25 allowing users to use as many cpu's per job as they see fit while still having a limit on hardware usage.